# Axios GET Request Returns 404 Error for API Route in Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, axios

I'm building a Next.js application where I'm trying to fetch product details using Axios from an API route. However, I'm encountering a "Request failed with status code 404" error, indicating that the requested resource was not found.

[image]

Here are the relevant code snippets for the files involved:

```
1.pages/admin/dashboard/product/create.js:
```

This is where the Axios GET request is being made to fetch product details. I've verified that the product.parent value contains a valid product ID before making the request.

```
/** @format */

import db from "@/utils/db";
import styles from "../../../../styles/products.module.scss";
import Layout from "@/components/admin/layout";
import Product from "@/models/Product";
import Category from "@/models/Category";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Form, Formik } from "formik";
import SingularSelect from "@/components/selects/SingularSelect";

const initialState = {
    name: "",
    description: "",
    brand: "",
    sku: "",
    discount: 0,
    images: [],
    description_images: [],
    parent: "",
    category: "",
    subCategories: [],
    color: {
        color: "",
        image: "",
    },
    sizes: [
        {
            size: "",
            qty: "",
            price: "",
        },
    ],
    details: [
        {
            name: "",
            value: "",
        },
    ],
    questions: [
        {
            question: "",
            answer: "",
        },
    ],
    shippingFee: "",
};
export default function create({ parents, categories }) {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState(initialState);
    const [subs, setSubs] = useState([]);
    const [colorImage, setColorImage] = useState("");
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    const [description_images, setDescription_images] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    console.log(product);
    useEffect(() => {
        const getParentData = async () => {
          const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/product/${product.parent}`);
          console.log(data);
          if (data) {
            setProduct({
              ...product,
              name: data.name,
              description: data.description,
              brand: data.brand,
              category: data.category,
              subCategories: data.subCategories,
              questions: [],
              details: [],
            });
          }
        };
        getParentData();
      }, [product.parent]);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getSubs() {
            const { data } = await axios.get("/api/admin/subCategory", {
                params: {
                    category: product.category,
                },
            });
            setSubs(data);
        }
            getSubs();
    }, [product.category]);
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { value, name } = e.target;
        setProduct({ ...product, [name]: value });
    };
    const validate = Yup.object({});
    const createProduct = async () => {};
    return (
        <Layout>
            <div className={styles.header}>create product</div>
            <Formik
                enableReinitialize
                initialValues={{
                    name: product.name,
                    brand: product.brand,
                    description: product.description,
                    category: product.category,
                    subCategories: product.subCategories,
                    parent: product.parent,
                    sku: product.sku,
                    discount: product.discount,
                    color: product.color.color,
                    imageInputFile: "",
                    styleInout: "",
                }}
                validationSchema={validate}
                onSubmit={() => {
                    createProduct();
                }}
            >
                {(fromik) => (
                    <Form>
                        {/* <Images name="imageInputFile"
          header="Product Carousel Image"
          text="add images"
          images={images}
          setImages={setImages}
          setColorImage={setColorImage}
          /> */}
                        <div className={styles.flex}>
                            {product.color.image && (
                                <img
                                    src={product.color.image}
                                    className={styles.image_span}
                                    alt=''
                                />
                            )}
                            {product.color.color && (
                                <span
                                    className={styles.color_span}
                                    style={{ background: `${product.color.color}` }}
                                ></span>
                            )}
                            {/* <Colors
                name="color"
                product={product}
                setProduct={setProduct}
                colorImage={colorImage}
              />
              <Style
                name="styleInput"
                product={product}
                setProduct={setProduct}
                colorImage={colorImage}
              /> */}
                            <SingularSelect
                                name='parent'
                                value={product.parent}
                                placeholder='Parent product'
                                data={parents}
                                header='Add to an existing product'
                                handleChange={handleChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
    db.connectDb();
    const results = await Product.find().select("name subProducts").lean();
    const categories = await Category.find().lean();
    db.disconnectDb();
    return {
        props: {
            parents: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)),
            categories: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categories)),
        },
    };
}
```

```
2.pages/api/product/[id].js:
```

This is the API route file responsible for fetching product details based on the provided ID. I've checked this file, and it seems to be correctly implemented.

```
import nc from "next-connect";
import db from "../../../utils/db";
import Product from "../../../models/Product";

const handler = nc();

handler.get(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    db.connectDb();
    const id = req.query.id;
    const style = req.query.style || 0;
    const size = req.query.size || 0;
    const product = await Product.findById(id).lean();
    let discount = product.subProducts[style].discount;
    let priceBefore = product.subProducts[style].sizes[size].price;
    let price = discount ? priceBefore - priceBefore / discount : priceBefore;
    db.disconnectDb();
    return res.json({
      _id: product._id,
      style: Number(style),
      name: product.name,
      description: product.description,
      slug: product.slug,
      sku: product.subProducts[style].sku,
      brand: product.brand,
      category: product.category,
      subCategories: product.subCategories,
      shipping: product.shipping,
      images: product.subProducts[style].images,
      color: product.subProducts[style].color,
      size: product.subProducts[style].sizes[size].size,
      price,
      priceBefore,
      quantity: product.subProducts[style].sizes[size].qty,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

export default handler;
```

```
3.pages/api/admin/subCategory.js:
```

```
handler.get(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { category } = req.query;
    console.log(category);
    if (!category) {
      return res.json([]);
    }
    db.connectDb();
    const results = await SubCategory.find({ parent: category }).select("name");
    console.log(results);
    db.disconnectDb();
    return res.json(results);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

I've checked the API route file (pages/api/product/[id].js), and it seems to be correctly implemented to fetch product details based on the provided ID. However, when making the Axios GET request from create.js, I'm getting the 404 error response.

I suspect there might be an issue with how Axios handles the GET request or a potential problem with my API route implementation. I'm unsure how to proceed with debugging this issue.

Could someone kindly guide me on how to troubleshoot and fix this "404" error for Axios GET requests in my Next.js application? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The path of your endpoint seems to be `/api/product/someproductid`, yet in your backend handler you have `const id = req.query.id;`   There is no `query` in your request (at least in the code you show), so you have to get the `id` from the path parameters, `const id = req.params.id;`

Comment: Is this line of code that you say causes this 404 error?

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the backend and check if your request reaches that partiuclar part of the code. Maybe not, because I don't see how this handler would return a 404. Check the network inspector of the browser to see what request is actually sent ...

Comment: I checked in the network section in the browser and saw that it sends the api section and sends the subCategory section, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: What subCategory?

Comment: In method getSubs() i request with axios and get subCategory data and I saw in the network browser and get data subcategory

Comment: Well, then maybe you should have mentioned that in your question. Please create a minimal reproducible example that shows the wrong behaviour. With the information currently given nobody will be able to help you, because it's 1. incomplete 2. unclear

Comment: Not in this section it gets the subcategories in the network section in the browser but my only problem is axios giving me a 404 error. I asked this question, how can I fix this 404 axios error?

Comment: Nobody can tell you how to "fix this 404 error" if we don't know what your code is actually doing  ... Ie we don't know *which* request returns a 404, we don't know how that request looks like, we don't even know whether you are showing us the code of the correct handler ...

Comment: I added the handler part in the subCategory file top

Comment: None of the handlers you showed will return a 404 error. They will either return a 500 or a 200 ...  Did you try as I suggested? Set a breakpoint at the backend and see if the request even reaches the respective handler. If not, there is either something wrong with your request or your routing is incorrect at the backend ...

Comment: All of your items are correct, but as I said, the status code returns 200 in the case of subCategory, but in the request section, where I checked the routing in the backend, there was no problem, there are only 2 or 3 items that give an error. Above is a picture. I put it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason could be that in your create.js component, you are using the useEffect to fetch parent data based on product.parent. However, you are using it in the URL without checking if it's a valid value. This can lead to a 404 error if the value of parent is invalid. You can add a condition to check that product.parent is not empty before making the GET request,

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const getParentData = async () => {
        if (product.parent) { // Check if product.parent is not empty
            try {
                // the axios call
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching parent data:", error)
            }
        }
    }
    getParentData()
}, [product.parent])
```

or something like this,

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const getParentData = async () => {
        try {
         // ... axios call
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching parent data:", error)
        }
    }
    
    if (product.parent) { // Call the function only when product.parent is not empty
        getParentData()
    }
}, [product.parent])
```

Also double check your db.connectDb() function. Should you not await for the connection to establish before proceeding?

```js
 await db.connectDb(); // Connect to the database
 await db.disconnectDb(); // Disconnect from the database
```

Comment: I did this but it shows error 404 in the console

Comment: please add the full error with your question.

Comment: Well, you are right, but I put the same parent value in the code and checked, but it does not show the error, but when I go to the console, it shows the same 404 error.

Comment: Above I put the error in full

Comment: @MiladHossainie-KAKASHEX please check my updated answer. If this doesn't solve your problem. then I recommend you log at every level to chase and verify all parameters. I am out of ideas.

Comment: I checked all the parameters, there is no problem, even in the Inspect section of the browser in the network section, I checked all the requests and saw that it sends the subCategory and the [id] section is also fine, and I don't know exactly where the problem is. Which brings me Archer Axios 404

Comment: I did OK with the database part in the getServerSideProps part and added await and the problem was not solved.